# Make a list contain the filename only from an appended path

Tags: python

I have the following code which appends images to a list. How can I loop through the images and display them one at a time?

Here is my code:

```
def getFiles(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".JPG"):
            list.append(os.path.join(path, file))
```

Instead of getting a list that has the following results:

```
["drive/img/img1.jpg", "drive/img/img2.jpg", ...]
```

I want to loop through that list and display each of the images.

Comment: Why not just append the file rather than joining with the path: `l.append(file)`?

Comment: Image won't be displayed when I do this.

Comment: This code doesn't display any images.

Comment: The code that I have in my question displays the image. But when I use append, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Of course, because `append` appends to a list and does not display an image.

Comment: As @Mark said the value you want to append to the list is in `file`. But you don't add `file` to the list, you append `os.path.join(path, file)`. BTW, where does `list` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite library to work with paths is `pathlib`. In this case you can leverage the `.suffix` and the `.name` attributes of the `Path` objects to loop through the files.
Then you can exploit `scikit-image` and `matplotlib` to show the images.

Here's some toy code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import skimage.io as io
import matplotlib.plotly as plt

path = Path(my_path)
fnames = list()
for p in path.iterdir():
    if p.suffix==".JPG":

        img = io.imread(p)
        plt.imshow(p)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. But my intention was to display the image after the list is created. When I try running the code using the IPython.display module nothing is displayed.

Comment: So you would like to loop through the images and display them one at a time?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Ok I edited the question to explain the real goal and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Took another look at it, This may work for you.

```py
def getFiles(path):
    mylist = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".JPG"):
            mylist.append(os.path.basename(file))
            test = Image(os.path.join(path, file))
            print(os.path.join(path, file))
            display(test)
```

This should do it.

```py
def getFiles(path):
    mylist = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".JPG"):
            mylist.append(os.path.basename(file))
    return mylist


images = getFiles("C:\\Images")

print(images)
```

Comment: Thanks. But my intention was to display the image after the list is created. When I try running the code using the IPython.display module nothing is displayed.

Comment: I believe you need to pass the entire path of the image file then. Not just the name of the file.

Comment: Hmmmm. Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following code.
In this case you split the name from the extension and only take into account the filename at position "[0]".

```
def getFiles(path):
 for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".JPG"):
        ll.append(file)
```

Comment: Thanks. But my intention was to display the image after the list is created. When I try running the code using the IPython.display module nothing is displayed.

Comment: ok ok :) , so.. you can remove a .split('.')[0]

Comment: Still not working. Guess providing the whole path is the only solution that will display the image :(